# Cannot access shared folder from Windows run command

Tags: shared-folders

I have a problem logging in to a shared folder on another computer named `jack` in my local network using the Windows `run` dialog.

If I type `\\jack` in the `run` dialog it returns the error

```
Windows cannot access \\jack

Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with
your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click
Diagnose.
```

If instead I type `\\jack\sharedfolder` in the `run` dialog, it works.  It also works if I try to log in to `\\jack` from Windows File Explorer.

I have never encountered this problem in the past, it only started about a month ago.

[image: screenshot here]

Answer (score 1):

By default, you are normally supposed to connect to a shared folder by //server/folder. When you enter \jack directly on the file explorer, it looks for folders that it CAN access (\jack\scan), but Run doesn't do that. It tried to directly connect without looking for folders connected to \jack and finds that it isn't a folder that it can access. If you want to go through Run, do \jack\scan for now, and if there are more folders available, just change it like this: \jack[name of new folder]

This is just how Windows works, and it is normal. Hope this helps. Ask if you have more questions.

Comment: This is not true dear friend , there is No problem entering this way do to \\jack from the run command , i have many computers with shared folders and im just entering \\name and then im getting the list of the folders that inside that share . lets say You are now entering to share folder in certain computer, you do not know what folders are there, so you must enter the main share by doing \\nameofthecomputer or \\ip , This problem is only on this computer

Comment: okay, and you tried using the ip instead, correct? Did you also try to connect using a different computer?

Comment: yes from ip its not working too and from many computers im getting the same error , no one cant access \\jack from run command , only from file explorer

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to do it through Run? Also, If it is working on other devices, then it could be something to do with \\jack

Comment: before two weeks its works great \\jack but now nothing , i must find the problem

Comment: I'd say first see what did you do before the problem started. You might've did something on \\jack, or Windows did something.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Windows versions (yours and `//jack`)

Comment: Use this article to check settings (especially services) on Jack: [support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf).  **Section: How do I troubleshoot sharing files and folders?**
Make sure that you reboot systems during testing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure permission via Computer Management or Windows Explorer? I had similar issue that I configured different user via these two places. One day, I gave them local access. After he accessed one of the shared folder locally, it totally messed up the access even though the permission list remained. I had to redo every permission just via a single place, which I chose "Windows Explorer".