# Debug UNC network share issues on Windows from the command line?

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-shares

I'm so tired of Windows updates breaking things; what a colossal waste of time it is to get things working again ...

My problem now is this: I'm trying to access local network NAS shares. After initially having a problem with it (which I cannot recall the solution for) that somehow got solved, I could do the following: open Windows Explorer; type `\\MYNAS\` in the address bar and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>; wait for 10-15 seconds and get presented with a login/passowrd prompt; enter login/password; get presented with a list of shares on the MYNAS on Windows Explorer.

Last I used this was a couple of weeks ago, when it was working - and when I tried it again now, it is broken: after I type `\\MYNAS\` in the address bar and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>; nothing happens for up to 30 seconds, and after that I get a message:

> Network Error
>
> WINDOWS cannot access \MYNAS\
>
> Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To Try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose.
>
> See details: Error code 0x80004005 ; Unspecified error

Click Diagnose:

> Troubleshooting has completed
>
> Troubleshooting was unable to automatically fix all of the issues found. You can find more details below.
>
> Problems found:
> file and print sharing resource (MYNAS) is online but isn't responding to connection attempts.
>
> Detection details:
> The remote computer isn’t responding to connections on port 445, possibly due to firewall or security policy settings, or because it might be temporarily unavailable. Windows couldn’t find any problems with the firewall on your computer.

There is also a Network Diagnostics Log trace file FD880924-C51B-4F01-8F5B-68996B46C749.Diagnose.0.etl there, 1024 KB, but when I try to open it

```
---------------------------  
Windows Performance Analyzer  
---------------------------  
Trace processing failed:  

[0x80070570] The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.  
---------------------------  
OK    
---------------------------
```

However, if I use local IP address instead of name, that is, I type `\\192.168.200.1\` in the address bar and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> then everything works - after wait for 10-15 seconds I get presented with a login/passowrd prompt; and when I enter login/password I get presented with a list of shares on the MYNAS on Windows Explorer. (so in that sense, my problem is similar to [Cannot access shared folder from Windows run command](https://superuser.com/questions/1779594/cannot-access-shared-folder-from-windows-run-command))

After finding a ton of useless articles on the web about this problem, one thing I tried was to look into firewall; I remember having turned off firewall when I installed this Windows 10 - but now when I checked Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance, I saw Network firewall: View in Windows Security, clicked that, and saw this window for the first time ever:

[image: windows security]

Everything was turned on here when I first saw it; as you can see, I had since turned off firewall for Domain Network and Private Network - but that does not help.

Also, in administrator command prompt, I get this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dir \\MYNAS\myshare
The network path was not found.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>net view \\MYNAS
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

So, I was wondering - is there a command line application, that I could use to troubleshoot network shares, which will provide details on exactly which steps are performed when trying to access a network share (similar to how `strace` on Linux shows which paths a program tries to access, or how `traceroute`/`TRACERT` shows through which machines does a TCP/IP packet get routed), so I could see exactly where the process gets stuck?